# Инлайн кнопки телеграм бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

SQL-запрос лежит в переменной,переменная прицепленна к кнопке. клиент нажимает кнопку и запрос(переменная улетает в базу) и возвращается выборка, которая показывается клиенту.
Вопрос: как сделать чтоб улетал запрос после нажатия? И убрать имя бота в запросе
Вот код кнопок:

```
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def process_command(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply("Нажмите одну из кнопок", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
    
        inline_kb_full = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(inline_btn_1)
        inline_kb_full.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Вторая кнопка', callback_data='btn2'))
        inline_btn_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 3', callback_data='btn3')
        inline_btn_4 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 4', callback_data='btn4')
        inline_btn_5 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 5', callback_data='btn5')
        inline_kb_full.add(inline_btn_3, inline_btn_4, inline_btn_5)
        inline_kb_full.row(inline_btn_3, inline_btn_4, inline_btn_5)
        inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("query=''", switch_inline_query=''))
        inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("query='qwerty'", switch_inline_query='qwerty'))
        inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("Inline в этом же чате", switch_inline_query_current_chat='wasd'))
        inline_kb_full.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Связаться с оператором', url=config.url))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой я вариант нашел: Кнопка ждет нажатие, получаем после клика имя кнопки, лезем в словарь, где имя кнопки ключ: запрос значение. и перебором вытаскиваем запрос и кладем в переменную button_request и кидаем его в базу. вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Нажмите одну из кнопок", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    button_push = callback_query
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
    print(button_push.data)
    push = button_push.data
    button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
    print(button_request)
```

Answer (score 1):

если вы хотите, что бы запрос в базу данных шел после нажатия кнопки, сделайте её в calldata

Comment: Покажите примером кода пожалста на одной какой-нибудь

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

если взять примером кода, то вот:

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    #Вот создание кнопки, можете поменять некоторые значения, и посмотреть что будет
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text='Test', callback_data='test')
    markup_inline.add(item)
    #Здесь идет текст, который сопрождает кнопки, можно и без него
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'x',
                        reply_markup=markup_inline
                        )

#Вот здесь нужно делать ответ на кнопки
@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):

    if call.data == 'test':
        #Ваш овтет на кнопку
    #И прошу заметить, что теперь в добавку к тексу нужно добавлять call вот пример:
    bot.send_message(call.chat.id, '')
```

Надеюсь я более менее ясно пояснил свои мысли, удачи Вам =)

Comment: Доброго Вам! падает вот с таким логом при старте бота:

File "/Users/PycharmProjects/chat_for_site/bot.py", line 18, in start
    dp.send_message(message.chat.id, 'x', reply_markup=markup_inline)
AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Добавил в вопрос весь код. не могли бы Вы его подправить?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, у меня просто были изначально ошибки из питоном, и я сменил переменную, вам нужно сменить client на  bot и ваша ошибка должна исчезнуть

Comment: Это я сразу убрал и ругался еще на func= убрал тоже. Если не сложно, можете мой код отредактировать хотя бы на примере 1й кнопки? я в вопрос полный код добавил

Answer (score 0):

Давайте я создам бота для одной кнопки, возможно вы поймете в чем ошибка=)

```
import telebot
import configure

bot = telebot.Telebot(configure.config['token'])
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def game(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    item_join = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='start', callback_data='test')
    markup_inline.add(item_join)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст',
                    reply_markup=markup_inline
                    )


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Hello')
```

И в месте из ботом создайте файл: 'configure' и запишите в нем этот код:

```
config = {
    'token': 'x'
}
```

Вместо х ваш токен на бота

Comment: Я надеюсь этот код хоть как-то поможет вашей проблеме=)

Comment: Прошу прощения, в этом варианте вот такая ошибка:

 bot = telebot.Telebot(configure.config)
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'

К тому же, насколько я понял, здесь событие по нажатию у Вас ТЕКСТ выводит, а мне надо в базу запрос кидать

Comment: Вы можете сменить текст на запрос в базу данных, а ошибка возможно потому что вы не загрузили библиотеку telebot

Comment: Если вам нужно установить библиотку, вы нажимаете win + R и в строке пишите cmd после этого у вас откроется окошко, и в черном окошке впишите такую команду pip install pytelegrambotapi(вроде бы правильно написал, если что-то не правильно написал гугл в помощь)